# How to keep the material search view opened by default

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using the https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView for Search view.
I want to keep the search view opened when I go to the materialsearchactivity..

[image: search view]

My current code is

```
public class search extends AppCompatActivity {
MaterialSearchView searchView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        searchView = (MaterialSearchView)findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search");
        searchView.showSearch();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);

        return true;
    }
}
```

According to Nayan Srivastava answer after updating it to the following code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        searchView = (MaterialSearchView)findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        searchView.performClick();
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search");
        searchView.showSearch();
    }
```

I am getting the following error..

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.buckydroid.anonchat, PID: 7850
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.buckydroid.anonchat/com.buckydroid.anonchat.search}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start this animator on a detached view!
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start this animator on a detached view!
                                                                           at android.view.RenderNode.addAnimator(RenderNode.java:786)
                                                                           at android.view.RenderNodeAnimator.setTarget(RenderNodeAnimator.java:300)
                                                                           at android.view.RenderNodeAnimator.setTarget(RenderNodeAnimator.java:282)
                                                                           at android.animation.RevealAnimator.<init>(RevealAnimator.java:37)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(ViewAnimationUtils.java:71)
                                                                           at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.utils.AnimationUtil.reveal(AnimationUtil.java:86)
                                                                           at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.setVisibleWithAnimation(MaterialSearchView.java:553)
                                                                           at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.showSearch(MaterialSearchView.java:519)
                                                                           at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.showSearch(MaterialSearchView.java:501)
                                                                           at com.buckydroid.anonchat.search.onCreate(search.java:25)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: The error is due to the animation : just use `searchView.showSearch(false);` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onCreateOptionsMenu` you can call `performClick`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView.setMenuItem(item);
    searchView.performClick();
    return true;
}
```

This should do the job.

Comment: After doing this I am getting an error. Updated the error log

Comment: try this in `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: instead try requestFocus();

Comment: Another question.. How can i send it back to previouss activity on back arrow click on the searchview .. It's taking me back to the toolbar

Comment: You need to enable, home buttons on activity. can u ask another question and post me the link otherwise it will mess here.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be due to the animation overlapping.To disable animation just use:

`searchView.showSearch(false);`

To answer the other question asked in the comments ( how to send it back to the previous activity)  use :

```
searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {
            //To close the current activity
              search.this.finish();
        }
    });
```